# How do you access argv/argc in Single Assignment C (SAC)?

Tags: command-line, command-line-arguments, argv

Is `argv` a SAC array of strings, or a traditional C array of strings?

There's [CommandLine.sac](http://www.sac-home.org/docs/libdoc/node85.html) in the docs, but I have no idea how to use SAC's API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In version (1.0) you can use the argv(1) function.

```
$ cat args.sac
use StdIO: all;
use Array: all;
use CommandLine: all;

int main() {
    printf("Test: %s\n", argv(1));

    return(0);
}
$./args hello
$ Test: hello
```

Answer (score 0):

SAC does neither (actually worse): SAC provides `argv()` in the `CommandLine` module, returning a string with all the arguments concatenated:

```
$ cat args.sac
use StdIO: all;
use Array: all;
use CommandLine: all;

int main() {
    printf("%s\n", argv());

    return(0);
}
$ sac2c -o args args.sac
$ ./args a b c
./args a b c
```